# How to filter img tag from the html in flutter

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress, flutter

I am making application in flutter using WordPress rest API.In **WordPress rest API post**  there is the property named **content which have further property rendered** as shown in the Json. In the rendered property there is a html tags. I only want to filter the img tag from there. How can i achieve this in dart or php?

```
        "id": 1660,
        "link": "http://localhost/soledesign/bill-baber/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "Bill Baber"
        },
        "content": {
            "rendered": "<h2>Bill Baber Knitwear opened our doors for the first time back in 1977 and have been producing the finest Scottish knitwear ever since.</h2>\n<p>Helen &amp; Bill Baber design and produce the whole collection themselves, with a little help from time to time. The collection includes mostly ladies wear, with some unisex styles, sorry guys! You’ll find full length silk jackets, luxuriously soft cashmere shawls, lightweight linen tops and stunning accessories to pep up any outfit. The widest selection can be found in store at <a href=\"https://billbaber.com/contact-us/\">66 Grassmarket</a>, however we do have a collection available <a href=\"https://billbaber.com/shop/\">online</a> for you to enjoy and we even supply other <a href=\"https://billbaber.com/stockists/\">retailers</a> all over the world!</p>\n<p>On this site you will see garments that we carry in stock or produce to order. in some cases we may hold a little stock ready to go, but generally each items is made from scratch when you order it. In store we have a boutique collection many of which simply cannot be reproduced, sometimes the yarn has run out or the style was a one off creation.</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/crail_silver-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Crail Top\" /><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/liscannor_crew-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Crew Jumper\" /><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/t_alt_dne-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Alto Top\" /><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/t_dtt_sge-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Dot\" /></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "excerpt": {
            "rendered": "<p>Bill Baber Knitwear opened our doors for the first time back in 1977 and have been producing the finest Scottish knitwear ever since. Helen &amp; Bill Baber design and produce the whole collection themselves, with a little help from time to time. The collection includes mostly ladies wear, with some unisex styles, sorry guys! You’ll [&hellip;]</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "author": 83
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/html 
Step 1: Remove special character and parse json string, you can see `Payload` class in full code

```
String result = jsonString.replaceAll("\n", "");
Payload payload = payloadFromJson(result);
```

Step 2: Get `DOM Element` with `querySelectorAll("img")`

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
...    

var document = parse(payload.content.rendered);
var imgList = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for (dom.Element img in imgList) {
  print(img.attributes["src"]);
  print(img.toString());
}
```

output

```
I/flutter (11892): https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/crail_silver-190x285.jpg
I/flutter (11892): https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/liscannor_crew-190x285.jpg
I/flutter (11892): https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/t_alt_dne-190x285.jpg
I/flutter (11892): https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/t_dtt_sge-190x285.jpg
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  int id;
  String link;
  Title title;
  Content content;
  Content excerpt;
  int author;

  Payload({
    this.id,
    this.link,
    this.title,
    this.content,
    this.excerpt,
    this.author,
  });

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        id: json["id"],
        link: json["link"],
        title: Title.fromJson(json["title"]),
        content: Content.fromJson(json["content"]),
        excerpt: Content.fromJson(json["excerpt"]),
        author: json["author"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "link": link,
        "title": title.toJson(),
        "content": content.toJson(),
        "excerpt": excerpt.toJson(),
        "author": author,
      };
}

class Content {
  String rendered;
  bool protected;

  Content({
    this.rendered,
    this.protected,
  });

  factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
        rendered: json["rendered"],
        protected: json["protected"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rendered": rendered,
        "protected": protected,
      };
}

class Title {
  String rendered;

  Title({
    this.rendered,
  });

  factory Title.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Title(
        rendered: json["rendered"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rendered": rendered,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<String>> _future;

  Future<List<String>> _getData() {
    String jsonString = r'''
    {
    "id": 1660,
        "link": "http://localhost/soledesign/bill-baber/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "Bill Baber"
        },
        "content": {
            "rendered": "<h2>Bill Baber Knitwear opened our doors for the first time back in 1977 and have been producing the finest Scottish knitwear ever since.</h2>\n<p>Helen &amp; Bill Baber design and produce the whole collection themselves, with a little help from time to time. The collection includes mostly ladies wear, with some unisex styles, sorry guys! You’ll find full length silk jackets, luxuriously soft cashmere shawls, lightweight linen tops and stunning accessories to pep up any outfit. The widest selection can be found in store at <a href=\"https://billbaber.com/contact-us/\">66 Grassmarket</a>, however we do have a collection available <a href=\"https://billbaber.com/shop/\">online</a> for you to enjoy and we even supply other <a href=\"https://billbaber.com/stockists/\">retailers</a> all over the world!</p>\n<p>On this site you will see garments that we carry in stock or produce to order. in some cases we may hold a little stock ready to go, but generally each items is made from scratch when you order it. In store we have a boutique collection many of which simply cannot be reproduced, sometimes the yarn has run out or the style was a one off creation.</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/crail_silver-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Crail Top\" /><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/liscannor_crew-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Crew Jumper\" /><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/t_alt_dne-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Alto Top\" /><img src=\"https://billbaber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/t_dtt_sge-190x285.jpg\" alt=\"Dot\" /></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "excerpt": {
            "rendered": "<p>Bill Baber Knitwear opened our doors for the first time back in 1977 and have been producing the finest Scottish knitwear ever since. Helen &amp; Bill Baber design and produce the whole collection themselves, with a little help from time to time. The collection includes mostly ladies wear, with some unisex styles, sorry guys! You’ll [&hellip;]</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "author": 83
}
    ''';

    String result = jsonString.replaceAll("\n", "");
    Payload payload = payloadFromJson(result);
    var document = parse(payload.content.rendered);
    var imgList = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    List<String> imageList = [];
    for (dom.Element img in imgList) {
      print(img.attributes["src"]);
      imageList.add(img.attributes["src"]);
    }
    return Future.value(imageList);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = _getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
            future: _getData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('Input a URL to start');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount:
                            snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                          );
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter images without converting the jsonString to raw String because values i am getting from the api and i  stored it in variable.@chunhunghan

Comment: Without convert json to model Payload. you can not parse it with document.querySelectorAll("img");

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: Can I use use ListView.builder() instead of for in loop.

Comment: I have update full code and working demo. you can check it.